# Is there reporting for commodities and forex trades?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, foreign-exchange, european-union, regulation

I was wondering why stock trades are required to be reported to the exchange or trade reporting facility, but why other asset types like commodities, forex etc. don't have to be reported? I couldn't find any sources of other type of reporting obligation.

(BTW I know why reporting is done, to make the market more transparent. Why shouldn't other markets do the same)

Comment: What country's regulations are you asking about? It varies across jurisdictions.

Comment: Good question, I'm in the Netherlands so general EU regulations are what I'm looking for. Still, the reply from S Spring is also quite valuable since I also want to know how it's done in the USA

Answer (score 2):

There are exchange-traded options and futures and there is a commodities commitment of traders report:

https://www.cftc.gov/MarketReports/CommitmentsofTraders/index.htm

Currency options and futures would be included but not Forex.

Comment: Can you explain what the difference is between currency options and futures and forex? I see forex as a shorthand for foreign currency exchange which covers the various spot transactions and forward transactions. As my knowledge goes, a currency forward is a currency future. Are the two similar? or do I need to brush up on my knowledge

Comment: Forex trading is over-the-counter with a counter-party but the counter-party likely just lays the position off with a bank. Currency futures and options are exchange traded contracts. Forex recognizes currency interest rates with a daily roll-over payment or charge. Futures are just priced different from the spot according to currency interest rates. Options are constructed from futures to make specific characteristics. For instance options have a fixed amount of financial risk but may have noticeable expense. Now, I'm using a U.S. trader's terminology not a legal terminology.